# How to get UTC Offset from a timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone

Using JavaScript, I need a way to get the local time of a client.

I do have the timezone of the client formatted like this:
Eastern Standard Time
Mountain Standard Time
Pacific Standard Time

1. Is there a way to get the UTC offset knowing the timezone as formatted above?
2. Or how can I get the current local time in "Pacific Standard Time"?

Comment: Create a table of timezone names and offsets, then look it up. There is no standard for civil timezone names and some names are used for more than one timezone.

Comment: Can you tell us how you obtained the time zone of the client?  That would help determine if those are identifiers or localized display strings.  Also, be sure to read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the section titled "Time Zone != Offset".

Comment: Also, if you just need the local time of the client, why do you need the time zone at all?  Is something wrong with `new Date().toString()`?  Are you running JavaScript on the client, or are you asking about Node.js server-side code?

Comment: `dateObj.getTimezoneOffset()` ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091399/1533592

Comment: This did not receive any answers. I have asked a similar question over here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77137664/how-to-get-utc-offsets-from-time-zones-of-a-particular-region

Comment: @MasterJoe Did you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34602679/1048572) to the question linked by dale?